# PowerApps : How to Navigate from Table to another Table

Tags: powerapps

I am really new to PowerApps.
What I want to ask is how to navigate the screen from table to another table, I have 2 tables named `table3` and `table2`

When I launch the apps for the first time, the datasource using `table3`
[image]

When I click the button I want to navigate to another table `table`, but it failed
[image]

The code I am using for when clicking the arrow button

```
Filter(Table3,Code in Table2.Club);Navigate(DetailScreen2, ScreenTransition.Fade)
```

and for code for displaying the second screen is this

```
BrowseGallery1.Selected
```

Here's my data for the datasource(using excel)
[image]

**UPDATE**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting confused with some terminology in PowerApps. An app in that platform consists of many *screens*, and you can *Navigate* from one screen to another. Each screen can have controls that displays data from (possibly) one or more tables. If you want to "navigate from one table to another", you need to create a couple of screens, one containing one of the tables, and another containing the other table, and navigate between them.

Another issue that I could find is your expression for the `OnSelect` property of the arrow:

```
Filter(Table3,Code in Table2.Club);Navigate(DetailScreen2, ScreenTransition.Fade)
```

The first part of that expression is not doing anything - a [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) function doesn't change any of its parameters; instead it *returns* a new table (not stored anywhere, just something that can be used as an input for another expression or a control).

If I understand correctly your scenario, you have two tables, and you want the user to select (in the browse screen) items from the first table (`table3`), and on the second (browse screen) you want to edit a single item from the second table (`table2`) - using the code from the first selection to find the item you want to display on the second table.

If this is the case, there are a few ways you can go about it. You can have in the `OnSelect` property of the arrow (in the gallery displaying data from `table3`) the following expression:

```
Navigate(DetailScreen2, ScreenTransition.Fade, { selectedCode: ThisItem.Code })
```

The [`Navigate` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-navigate) can take an optional third parameter, a *context* that will be passed to the next screen. This way, in the screen `DetailScreen2` you can reference the context variable `code`, and configure the display form with the following properties:

```
DataSource: table2
Item: LookUp(table2, Code = selectedCode)
```

The [`Lookup` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) will return an item from the second table, which then can be displayed in the form for that screen.

Comment: this for your explanation it works fine. when i click the record with `000` it navigate to `DetailScreen2` with code `000` (it works) but when i try other row like code `005` it navigate to `DetailScreen2` with code `000`. i have update

Comment: I saw on your screenshot that you have the expression `LookUp(Table2, Code = Code)` - I believe there's a conflict between the context variable `Code` and the field `Code` from your table. To prevent that, try changing the variable name to something else. For example, in the first screen, you'd have this for hte arrow's OnSelect: `Navigate(DetailScreen2, ScreenTransition.Fade, { selectedCode: ThisItem.Code })`, and in the Item property for the form you would have `LookUp(Table2, Code = selectedCode)`. I'll update the expressions in the answer as well.

Comment: it works, thanks. it's totally different from program language(C#) =.= ,

Comment: can you give me a reference to learn more about this power apps (more like syntax or code)

Comment: The documents at https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/guided-learning/ are a good start. It's definitely not an imperative language, it's more of a declarative language, whose syntax is similar to Excel's.

Comment: You can also look at https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/formula-reference for reference documentation for the PowerApps formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ware that forms don't accept tables from static excel files. Two potential methods to do this. 
1. Create the second table as a gallery. Connect to table2 and item set to `BrowseGallery1.Selected`. I deleted the arrow button and changed border so that it looks more like display.

[image]

2. Store your excel file to some cloud storage, for example, SharePoint, OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropdox. PowerApps can directly create this app automatically. So that this app is connected to data as well. [Check this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-excel)

Comment: what does ` 1. Create the second table as a gallery` means ?
for my environment in my excel file contains 2 tables which already uploaded to one drive. i think my error is the code